# Test String.prototype.function Using Mocha/Chai

Tags: javascript, function, testing, mocha.js, chai

How could you test a function with Mocha/Chain which is defined as String.prototype.testFunction? For example

Function:

```
String.prototype.testFunction = (x, y) => {
  return this.z + x + y
}

module.export = String.prototype.testFunction
```

Use of Function:

```
"Text".testFunction(1, 2)
```

From previous experience from testing functions it should be as follows:

```
const app = require("../index.js")

it('description', function(){
  var variable = "Test".app.testFunction(" ", "text")
  variable.should.equal("Test text")
})
```

Will this work? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Added function in separate js file and import the function as a constant in the test file